# Entity Framework 4 and POCO

Tags: entity-framework, entity, poco

I'm trying to get started using the latest Entity Framework 4 release on Visual Studio 2010 to create a simple WCF application. I would really like to start using POCO objects as opposed to EntityObject classes to serialize. I have been looking for some good write-ups about how to implement custom POCO mappings for Entity Objects but can't find anything recent.

I'm particularly interested in how to create custom mappings as opposed to having to create POCO objects with identical field names to their database counterparts.

Can anyone point me towards some good resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these:

[EF Feature CTP4 Walkthrough: Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4codefirstwalkthrough.aspx)

[Walkthrough: POCO Template for the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Steve, these are just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone point me towards some good resources?

It depends on your level of comfort dealing with EF and T4. You can also check out a tweaked version of EF templates which could open more possibilities for you.

Entity Framework Interface Generator

https://entityinterfacegenerator.codeplex.com

This project contains customized T4 templates which can generate interfaces and attributes for the DbContext class and entity classes.